# A question about the properties of global differentials

Tags: smooth-manifolds, tangent-bundle

[image]

[image]

These are from p.68 of John Lee's Introduction to Smooth Manifolds. There are no specific comments on what $M$ and $N$ are. But, I think they must be smooth manifolds with or without boundary. Is my judgement correct?

Comment: Of course thay are.

Comment: This is a convention that I explained in the middle of page 37: if I write “$F\colon M \to N$ is a smooth map,” it’s to be understood that $M$ and $N$ are smooth manifolds with or without boundary.

Comment: Oh, you are the author of this book! Thank you for your answer.